# Continuously write to TCP socket without reading

Tags: tcp

I have a TCP client server application written on boost 1.53. Based on the client command I have to start a server thread to write some data to a socket. But I have no guarantee that the client application would start reading from this socket.
Is there any trouble writing data to a socket without reading from it? Won't be there any socket overflow or data corruption ?

Looking forward to hearing your ideas.

Thx,
Dmitry

Comment: Either show the relevant code, or remove the language/library tags.

Comment: Or read about sliding window algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol

Answer (score 3):

What happens when sending data to a slow or non-cooperative remote side is covered by the [flow control aspect of TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control).

Suppose you try to send data and the application in the remote side refuses to read it. Eventually the remote side's receive window becomes full, and it will indicate this by sending an ACK with a window size 0. Your network stack stops trying send new packets until an ACK with a larger window size is received. If you keep trying to send data it accumulates in the send buffer in your network stack. When the buffer becomes full writing to your side of the socket blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Using TCP, that won't be a problem.  The server will detect that the client isn't reading, and hold off on sending more data until the client has acknowledged receipt of the already-sent data.  In this case the server thread will block until the client is ready to accept more data.

Also TCP packets are checksummed, so if any get corrupted in transit the client will reject them and the server will resend them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a feedback. Could you please provide some more details for your comment below :

"The server will detect that the client isn't reading, and hold off on sending more data until the client has acknowledged receipt of the already-sent data."

What is the detection mechanism here? Should I take care of it or this is done automatically by the TCP/IP stack?

Comment: The detection mechanism is the sliding window protocol that @MarcinLos linked to above.  It's done automatically for you by the TCP/IP stack, so you don't need to implement it yourself.

Comment: I've just read the article - thanks a lot for your help. Best wishes :)